# When are simple holonomic D-modules of the form $\mathcal{D}/\mathcal{D}L$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra

Let $\mathcal{D}=\mathcal{D}_X$ be the sheaf of rings of differential operators on a smooth algebraic curve $X$.

Since $\dim X=1$, the D-modules of the form $\mathcal{D}/\mathcal{D}L$ are necessarily holonomic. Conversely, I've verified that a holonomic D-module over $\mathbb{A}^1$ or $\mathbb{G}_m$ is always cyclic; i.e., of the form $\mathcal{D}/I$ for some (not necessarily principal) left-ideal $I$.

(As W. Sawin nicely remarked, this is obvious whenever the holonomic D-module $M$ is simple. But even then, it's not clear to me that the left-ideal $I$ in $M=\mathcal{D}/I$ is principal.)

**I wonder if it's true that every simple holonomic D-module over $X$, assumed to be a curve, is of the form $\mathcal{D}/\mathcal{D}L$.** If this is false in general, is it true for $X=\mathbb{A}^1$? For $X=\mathbb{G}_m$? For elliptic curves?

Comment: If a module were not cyclic, wouldn't the submodule generated by one element be a counterexample to the claim that it's simple?

Comment: Every holonomic D-module is locally cyclic. Are you asking if this is true globally?

Comment: Dear @user2520938, I'm asking more than that. I'm asking if, in a curve, every *simple* holonomic D-module is of the form D/DL. That is, it's cyclic (i.e., of the form D/I) and the left ideal I is principal.

Comment: @WillSawin thank you for your remark. I indeed proved that a (not necessarily simple) holonomic D-module over $\mathbb{G}_m$ is cyclic (this is also well-known for $\mathbb{A}^n$). But yeah, the simple case is indeed simpler ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $X$ is a smooth proper curve of positive genus, then there exist simple $D$-modules which have no global sections at all. This is because every degree $0$ line bundle admits a flat connection (since the obstruction to a connection is the Atiyah class which vanishes). The line bundle with connection gives a $D$-module, and as soon as the module is trivial, has no global sections.

Since it has no global sections, it admits no nontrivial map from $\mathcal D$ and hence can't be a quotient of $\mathcal D$.

If $X$ is an affine curve, a $\mathcal D$-module is an honest module and not a sheaf of modules. So it has plenty of global sections. For a holonomic $D$-module, the space of proper submodules is finite-dimensional and each one has infinite codimension, so one can choose an element that is outside all of them, showing that the module has the form $\mathcal D/\mathcal D I$.

However, $I$ need not be principal, unless $X$ has genus $0$ and the module is simple. This is because the quotient by the ideal generated by a differential operator of degree $d$ has generic rank $d$.

If we choose a $D$-module of generic rank $0$, supported at a single point, say, then the generic rank is $0$, so if the ideal is principal it must be generated by some function on $X$, necessarily vanishing only at that point.

It follows that every module of the form $\mathcal D/ DL$ supported at a single point is simple, which is why the simple assumption is necessary, and that this can only happen if the point generates a finite subgroup of the Picard group, which is why the genus $0$ assumption is necessary.

So your desired property can only be true for curves of genus $0$.

Comment: Dear @WillSawin, thank you very much for your answer! Do you know something about the converse? That is, $X$ is a curve of genus 0, is the desired property true? Is is true for $\mathbb{A}^1$ or $\mathbb{G}_m$?

Comment: Dear @WillSawin, I still don't know the answer of the converse (which was my main goal and was the reason for the bounty) but, since no one answered, I'll gladly give the bounty to you :)